# IF Statement not working in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, powershell-2.0

I've been trying to get an IF-ELSE clause to work within my little powershell v2 script, and I think I'm having some problems with my parsing. Here's the code I have currently:

```
$dir = test-path C:\Perflogs\TestFolder 

IF($dir -eq "False") 
{
New-Item C:\Perflogs\TestFolder -type directory
get-counter -counter $p -Continuous | Export-Counter  C:\PerfLogs\TestFolder\Client_log.csv -Force -FileFormat CSV -Circular -MaxSize $1GBInBytes
}
Else
{
get-counter -counter $p -Continuous | Export-Counter  C:\PerfLogs\TestFolder\Client_log.csv -Force -FileFormat CSV -Circular -MaxSize $1GBInBytes
}
```

So basically I want it to establish the $dir variable as testing to see if the path I want exists. If it doesn't, it should create that folder and run the counters. If it does, it should not create the folder but should still run counters.

I've got $p defined elsewhere, and the get-counters statement works fine. Right now, whether the folder exists or not I'm getting an error about new-item not working.

Am I using the wrong operator for -eq after doing that test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have:

```
if ($dir -eq $false)
```

because the string `"False"` is not equal to the boolean value `$false`.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this:

```
IF($dir -eq "False")
```

to this:

```
IF($dir -eq $false)
```

Answer (score 1):

x0n already answered, so I wont repeat that, but I noticed another "Gotcha" you should be aware of.

Your code is trying to test for the existence of a directory "TestFolder", however you test-path command is not restricted to checking only for directories.  Meaning, if you actually happen to have a file by the same name "TestFolder" it will still return true.

To be more careful, you should add the "-PathType Container" switch so that it will fail if there is a file by that name and only pass if there is a directory by that name.

`$dir = test-path C:\Perflogs\TestFolder -PathType Container`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers about `$false`, I've had syntax issues with v3. Specifically

```
if($dir -eq $false)
{
```

didn't work.

```
if($dir -eq $false){
```

did work. YMMV, but you've been warned.

Comment: this is nonsense. both styles work fine. this is not javascript.

Comment: @x0n - It's not nonsense. I've experienced the same behavior in v 5.1.

Comment: Update on placement of opening curly bracket: On closer inspection, it now appears that I do not experience the above behavior with `if`, but it is happening when piping output to `ForEach-object`. I.e., if I pipe output to `ForEach-object` and if the opening curly bracket after `ForEach-object` is on the next line instead of on the same line, then I get the run-time prompt: "cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1 / Supply values for the following parameters: / Process[0]:" However, that prompt does not occur if I put a line continuation back-tick after `ForEach-object`.

Answer (score 0):

It might work
If($? -ne 0)

if the given condition is false, which is defined in earlier variables(This is not for the above question)

If($dir -contains 'False')